# "To come undone"

Tags: meaning, figurative, songs

"Oh, it'll take a little time, might take a little crime to **come undone**
(...)
Who do you need, who do you love, when you **come undone**?"

Please, can someone help me with this? I'm pretty sure that they're not talking about unfastened shoelaces or open gifts int his song. Thanks in advance!
;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's interpretation of song lyrics

Comment: There's a web site that has this sort of thing: http://songmeanings.com

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, those damn song lyrics.  We wouldn't want anyone to learn what *come undone* means.

Comment: @deadrat: If it hadn't been *Duran Duran*, I'd have taken it for granted that ***crime*** deliberately alluded to doing something "naughty, wicked" (in the *erotic* sense), so what ***comes undone*** would suggest buttons and zips being unfastened while getting ***down and dirty***. But I think that's perhaps unlikely from Princess Di's favourite boy band.

Comment: Well I thought that even in a song lyric an expression wouldn't lose its meaning... I mean, if "to come undone" has a figurative and a real meaning, they are the same in a song or anywhere else, right? Or am I that wrong? :O Please help!

Comment: @deadrat that's a very interesting point of view :)

Comment: Do I have to mark these kind of comments as sarcastic?  Because I will if it's necessary.  It's just takes the fun out of it for me.

Comment: When was I sarcastic? No man, not at all. I guess I've mentioned you, instead of @FumbleFingers because he wrote something that I liked it, and in my opinion that was a very interesting point of view. By the way, why are people so agressive in this site? That's supposed to be a place where people ask, and other people answer, right? Why do people take a question for an offense?! It makes no sense at all. :/

Comment: No, no.  Do I have to mark my *own* comments as sarcastic.  Do you understand my comment to FumbleFingers now?  Some people are aggressive here because they have a high opinion of the site as a quasi-academic repository of knowledge and sanctuary of scholars.  In their view this is supposed to be a place where the right people ask the right questions for the right people to give the right answers.

Comment: Song lyrics (and titles) often contain meanings hidden behind word play.  Meaning aren't "lost"; they're multiplied.  Consider "Take Five" Paul Desmond's composition for the Dave Brubeck Quartet's album *Time Out*.  "Take Five" means take (five minutes for) a break, which plays on the same meaning of "time out."  But it also refers to the work's unusual 5/4 tempo.

Comment: @deadrat "the right people ask the right questions for the right people to give the right answers" CORRECT and sad, at the same time :S

Comment: Érika: I think we can take it for granted that *undone* above relates to the sense [*brought to destruction or ruin*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undone). But my second comment was partly intended to show *why* questions like this aren't a good fit for ELU. I'd say it's pretty certain Duran Duran wouldn't have intended the "smutty" allusions I brought up - but you didn't provide the source reference, so if I'd posted that interpretation as an answer and no-one *else* flagged up the source, it might well have got a lot of upvotes. There is no "right" answer - it's essentially Lit Crit.